CRC16 CRC-CCITT (0xFFFF) function with PL/pgSQL
How to compute  CRC16 CRC-CCITT (0xFFFF) function with PL/PGSQL , the same way as MySQL?
Code Function for PL/PGSQL
I try  to convert from MYSQL to  PL/PGSQL

DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `CRC16`( _STRING VARCHAR(25)) RETURNS varchar(50) CHARSET utf8mb4
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE _myCRC integer;
    DECLARE _ord INTEGER;
    DECLARE _n Integer;
    DECLARE _m Integer;
    DECLARE _strlend Integer;
    SET _myCRC := x'FFFF';

      SET _n  := 1;  
      SET _strlend := LENGTH(_STRING) ;
      
        loop_crc:  LOOP
     
            IF  _n > _strlend THEN 
                LEAVE  loop_crc;
            END  IF;
              
            SET _ord := ORD(SUBSTRING(_STRING, _n, 1) );
            SET _myCRC :=  _myCRC ^ _ord;
            SET _m := 0;     
            loop_bit:  LOOP
                IF  _m = 8 THEN 
                    LEAVE  loop_bit;
                END  IF;
                IF (_myCRC & x'0001') = x'0001' THEN
                    SET _myCRC := (_myCRC >> 1) ^ x'A001';
                ELSE
                    SET _myCRC := _myCRC >> 1;        
                END IF;
                SET  _m := _m + 1;
            END LOOP;
            SET  _n := _n + 1;

        END LOOP;

      return HEX(_myCRC); 
 END//
DELIMITER ;

here from MySQL

What's keeping you from converting the code? What is your question?

first time  i'm not successful from converting between mysql and plsql.
it had many errors such as   value is not in range . symbol ^ in mysql  , hex code in mysql and plsql.   syntax it's not same .  and then  i asked the question.   but now  i finished and i'm successful converting.

I guess this question should be closed then.

Or better yet, provide below the answer to your question yourself.

I solved my question  this's my function CRC16 CRC-CCITT (0xFFFF) for PL/PGSQL. Thanks you
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."qr_crc16"("_string" varchar)
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."varchar" AS $BODY$

 DECLARE 
 crc int;
 len int;
 ord int;
 i int;
 
       crc_table bigint[] = ARRAY(SELECT ('x' || lpad(hex, 8, '0'))::bit(32)::int AS int_val
FROM  (
   VALUES
     ('0000'), ('1021'), ('2042'), ('3063'), ('4084'), ('50A5'), ('60C6'), ('70E7'), 
            ('8108'), ('9129'), ('A14A'), ('B16B'), ('C18C'), ('D1AD'), ('E1CE'), ('F1EF'), 
            ('1231'), ('0210'), ('3273'), ('2252'), ('52B5'), ('4294'), ('72F7'), ('62D6'), 
            ('9339'), ('8318'), ('B37B'), ('A35A'), ('D3BD'), ('C39C'), ('F3FF'), ('E3DE'), 
            ('2462'), ('3443'), ('0420'), ('1401'), ('64E6'), ('74C7'), ('44A4'), ('5485'), 
            ('A56A'), ('B54B'), ('8528'), ('9509'), ('E5EE'), ('F5CF'), ('C5AC'), ('D58D'), 
            ('3653'), ('2672'), ('1611'), ('0630'), ('76D7'), ('66F6'), ('5695'), ('46B4'), 
            ('B75B'), ('A77A'), ('9719'), ('8738'), ('F7DF'), ('E7FE'), ('D79D'), ('C7BC'), 
            ('48C4'), ('58E5'), ('6886'), ('78A7'), ('0840'), ('1861'), ('2802'), ('3823'), 
            ('C9CC'), ('D9ED'), ('E98E'), ('F9AF'), ('8948'), ('9969'), ('A90A'), ('B92B'), 
            ('5AF5'), ('4AD4'), ('7AB7'), ('6A96'), ('1A71'), ('0A50'), ('3A33'), ('2A12'), 
            ('DBFD'), ('CBDC'), ('FBBF'), ('EB9E'), ('9B79'), ('8B58'), ('BB3B'), ('AB1A'), 
            ('6CA6'), ('7C87'), ('4CE4'), ('5CC5'), ('2C22'), ('3C03'), ('0C60'), ('1C41'), 
            ('EDAE'), ('FD8F'), ('CDEC'), ('DDCD'), ('AD2A'), ('BD0B'), ('8D68'), ('9D49'), 
            ('7E97'), ('6EB6'), ('5ED5'), ('4EF4'), ('3E13'), ('2E32'), ('1E51'), ('0E70'), 
            ('FF9F'), ('EFBE'), ('DFDD'), ('CFFC'), ('BF1B'), ('AF3A'), ('9F59'), ('8F78'), 
            ('9188'), ('81A9'), ('B1CA'), ('A1EB'), ('D10C'), ('C12D'), ('F14E'), ('E16F'), 
            ('1080'), ('00A1'), ('30C2'), ('20E3'), ('5004'), ('4025'), ('7046'), ('6067'), 
            ('83B9'), ('9398'), ('A3FB'), ('B3DA'), ('C33D'), ('D31C'), ('E37F'), ('F35E'), 
            ('02B1'), ('1290'), ('22F3'), ('32D2'), ('4235'), ('5214'), ('6277'), ('7256'), 
            ('B5EA'), ('A5CB'), ('95A8'), ('8589'), ('F56E'), ('E54F'), ('D52C'), ('C50D'), 
            ('34E2'), ('24C3'), ('14A0'), ('0481'), ('7466'), ('6447'), ('5424'), ('4405'), 
            ('A7DB'), ('B7FA'), ('8799'), ('97B8'), ('E75F'), ('F77E'), ('C71D'), ('D73C'), 
            ('26D3'), ('36F2'), ('0691'), ('16B0'), ('6657'), ('7676'), ('4615'), ('5634'), 
            ('D94C'), ('C96D'), ('F90E'), ('E92F'), ('99C8'), ('89E9'), ('B98A'), ('A9AB'), 
            ('5844'), ('4865'), ('7806'), ('6827'), ('18C0'), ('08E1'), ('3882'), ('28A3'), 
            ('CB7D'), ('DB5C'), ('EB3F'), ('FB1E'), ('8BF9'), ('9BD8'), ('ABBB'), ('BB9A'), 
            ('4A75'), ('5A54'), ('6A37'), ('7A16'), ('0AF1'), ('1AD0'), ('2AB3'), ('3A92'), 
            ('FD2E'), ('ED0F'), ('DD6C'), ('CD4D'), ('BDAA'), ('AD8B'), ('9DE8'), ('8DC9'), 
            ('7C26'), ('6C07'), ('5C64'), ('4C45'), ('3CA2'), ('2C83'), ('1CE0'), ('0CC1'), 
            ('EF1F'), ('FF3E'), ('CF5D'), ('DF7C'), ('AF9B'), ('BFBA'), ('8FD9'), ('9FF8'), 
            ('6E17'), ('7E36'), ('4E55'), ('5E74'), ('2E93'), ('3EB2'), ('0ED1'), ('1EF0')
 
   ) AS t(hex));

 begin

  
    crc := ('x' || lpad('FFFF', 8, '0'))::bit(32)::int;
    len := length(_string);
        
  for i in 1..len loop
    
             
            --  RAISE NOTICE ' i % ', SUBSTRING(_string, i, 1) ;
                
            --  RAISE NOTICE ' ASCII % ', ASCII(SUBSTRING(_string, i, 1));
             
              ord := (crc >> 8)  # ASCII(SUBSTRING(_string, i, 1));

            --  RAISE NOTICE ' ord % ', ord;
                
              crc :=  (crc << 8 &   ('x' || lpad('ffff', 8, '0'))::bit(32)::int) # crc_table[ord+1]; 
                    
            --  RAISE NOTICE ' tbl % ', crc_table[206];
            --  RAISE NOTICE 'crc % ', crc;
            --  RAISE NOTICE 'hex % ', to_hex(crc);

  end loop;


  return upper(to_hex(crc));
end; $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100

If put 123456789 . result is 29B1
